# I get error on sending email with laravel

Tags: laravel, symfony, email, error-handling, send

I have a laravel app. I sent an email with the following configuration,

```
MAIL_MAILER=sendmail 
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=fatemehmansoorypoor@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

It works locally but when I upload my app on cpanel it doesn't work with this error,

```
Call to undefined function Symfony\Component\Mailer\Transport\Smtp\Stream\proc_open()
```

Why?
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: do you have the `config\mail.php` the key `sendmail` ? with `'transport'  => 'smtp',` ?

Comment: @francisco by adding this 'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            // 'path' => env('MAIL_SENDMAIL_PATH', '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs -i'),
            'path' =>  '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs -i',
        ], now get this error Undefined array key "host"

Comment: your host by default is `'host'=> env('MAIL_HOST'),`

Comment: @francisco I have this  'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'url' => env('MAIL_URL'),
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.googlemail.com'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN','mary1800.info'),
        ], in mail.php. what should i do

Comment: if your `MAIL_MAILER=sendmail` then, config should be: 

 'sendmail' => [ 'transport' => 'smtp', 'url' => env('MAIL_URL'), 'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.googlemail.com'), 'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465), 'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'), 'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'), 'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'), 'timeout' => null, 'local_domain' => env('MAIL_EHLO_DOMAIN','mary1800.info'), ]

Comment: @francisco change sendmail mail.phph and now get error Connection could not be established with host "ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465": stream_socket_client(): Unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Network is unreachable). please help me. thanks

Comment: You should check with your web host to see what methods of email delivery they support. Some permit you sending via the servers sendmail/SMPTE serverl others require you to use a relay (either theirs or your own) or you can look into using a supported third party transactional mail server (which has lots of benefits).